# Mysql Query Update With Conditions

Tags: mysql, join, conditional-statements

i have an existing Mysql Table with Data Loaded(TblParts)

```
Code Stock Price Location id
1     10   1000   Global  1
2     5    1500   Office  2
3     2    500    Global  3
4     1    100    Global  4
```

i Have a Second Table with New information(TblNewParts)

```
Code Stock Price Location id
1    30    2000    Global 1
2    5     1000    Global 2
3    10    5000    Global 3
4    30    200     Global 4
5    40    500     Global 5
```

i need to update TblParts with TblPartsNew data

if Code Exist, And Location = Global then Update Stock and Price if Code Exist, But Location <> Global then Insert Record with Same Code and Distinct Location if code Not Exist then Add it

The Output of TblParts Must Be:

```
Code Stock Price Location
1    30    2000   Global 
2    5     1500   Office 
3    10    5000   Global 
4    30    200    Global 
5    40    500    Global
```

Comment: what is your question? Did you tried it, already ?

Comment: Because MySql hasn't MERGE command you must write an INSERT an a UPDATE query

Comment: @JoeTaras Why? What's wrong with `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax?

Comment: @Strawberry: Right! I've forgot it ;)

Comment: @JoeTaras I guess that's why they put the DELETE button there.

Comment: i havent got idea how can i perform that query.

Comment: I Can use that query because The ID Of tableNewParts is not the same of the TblParts. I Need Compare with Code and Location

Answer (score 0):

step 1: create a **primary key** for columns (code,location) using the below query

```
alter table TblParts add constraint pk_1 PRIMARY KEY(Code,Location);
```

step 2: now update the table with **TableNewParts** tables's data using below query

```
insert into TblParts(Code,Stock,Price,Location) select (Code,Stock,Price,Location) from TblNewParts on duplicate key update Stock=values(Stock),Price=values(Price);
```

Comment: Thnks, I Can use that query because The ID Of tableNewParts is not the same of the TblParts. I Need Compare with Code and Location.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/* if Code Exist, And Location = Global then Update Stock and Price */
UPDATE 
  tblparts p INNER JOIN tblnewparts np 
    ON np.code = p.code AND p.location = 'Global' 
SET p.price = np.price, p.stock = np.stock;

/* if Code Exist, But Location <> Global then Insert Record with Same Code */
/* and Distinct Location */ 
/* if code Not Exist then Add it */
INSERT INTO tblparts (code, stock, price, location)
  SELECT code, stock, price, location 
  FROM tblnewparts np
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tblparts 
                     WHERE (code = np.code AND location = np.location) 
                           OR 
                        (code= np.code))
```

Don't know what the ID column stands for. If it is an autoincremented key just add 0 to the fields list under the INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO tblparts (code, stock, price, location, id)
  SELECT code, stock, price, location, 0 
  FROM tblnewparts np
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tblparts 
                     WHERE (code = np.code AND location = np.location) 
                           OR 
                        (code= np.code))
```